# Removing zeros from table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to create a table in Python using Pandas crosstab function. I've managed to get the data to produce a table, however, it is not very readable. What I am trying to do is remove the 0s from the table.

The table looks like this at the moment:

[image: Pandas crosstab table]

I'm wondering if it possible to remove the 0s, or if there is a better way to produce this table.

Edit: by remove, I mean remove/don't display, in the table. Need to keep the data in the original data source.

Comment: remove zero ? then you will not have the same shape of your table

Comment: What do you mean by remove? This seems more of an issue caused by your buckets being 0.1 large. Why not define bigger buckets then pd.crosstab on those?

Comment: Have clarified in edits

Comment: `df.where(df==1,'')`?

Comment: @Wen-Ben where would that be added into the crosstab command?

Comment: Have you considered displaying this as an image where 0=black, 1=gray, and 2=white?

Comment: @StephenMeschke not sure how I'd achieve that

Comment: @Clauric I wrote an answer that explains how to visualize a Pandas DataFrame as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualize the array as an image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# Read data from .csv file
df = pd.read_csv('/home/stephen/Desktop/data.csv')
# Convert image to an array
img = np.array(df, np.float32)
# Scale image so values are from 0 to 1
img = img/np.amax(img)
# Resize so it's easier to see
img = cv2.resize(img, (420,420))
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image][image: numbers]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this will help, but you can try:

```
df.replace(0, np.nan)
```

I will give you a bunch on nan, but you will not lose the data type, just in case you want to perform any math. If this is not a problem, you can replace with the np.nan with 0. You need to import numpy as np.